# Read Azure Event Hub streams using oauth2 (using java client)

Tags: java, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-eventhub

I configure an event hub to receive audit and signin logs
No I need to read the events from event hub using any java client
The way to read is just open for now (I believe there is no REST API to read data)
I was successfully able to read event hub by code from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/tree/master/samples/Java/Basic/ReceiveByDateTime) by hardcoding SASKey and other configurations.

But what I want now is to use my favorite oath2 flow.

Where the Azure AD application reside in another tenant.
There will be a link for me to authenticate that app.
That app will obtain an access token once I accept the concent, then it will use that access token to read data from my event hub

Comment: Look here for AAD auth to Event Hubs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-role-based-access-control There is an example using .NET, don't know if this also applies to Java.

Comment: But I need example for java implementation.
Any java libraries?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send

Comment: Okay I got the answer after lot of searches.
As I researched there is no java SDK out there to use oauth flow directly.

But we can ask a user to grant permission to management API (user impersanation).
And then can use this authorization to read available eventhubs and assosiated SAS keys
And we can use above retrieved SASKey to consume eventhub data.
Sample code at : https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/tree/master/samples/Java/Basic/ReceiveUsingOffset